# A game with coloured animal tiles & figurines of Chinese men

Tags: identify-this-game

I once found some tiles that each have an animal on them, and some small statuettes of old Chinese men. Like this:

[image: Figures]

Can anybody identify what this is for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/3147/mandarin

Its Mandarin, a Chinese Zodiac game by Mattel.

Comment: Thanks, though I found it last night while looking through the conservatory...